# Fastest Way to Find the Closest Element to Another Element whose Value is Less in R

Tags: r

I have this loop that assigns the value to an element in branch.from that represents the index of the closest (while less than) whose value is less than the value of the corresponding element in branch.

```
for (j in 2:length(branch)) {
  branch.from[j]<-max(which(branch[1:(j-1)]<=branch[j]))
}
```

branch has just over 8 million elements, so this takes too long for my liking. Is there a faster way?
For example,

```
branch[1:20]<-c(1,54,25,54,22,54,36,54,43,54,40,54,27,54,34,54,26,54,32,54)
```

The above code gives,

```
branch.from[1:20]<-c(1,1,1,3,1,5,5,7,7,9,7,11,5,13,13,15,5,17,17,19)
```

[image: Branching Example]

Comment: Could you pls add a sample of the vectors `branch` and `branch.from` (no need to have same size as your own data, but maybe keep the same ratio for their size).

Comment: @DominicComtois, I hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry I can't figure out the logic... I did `cbind(branch, closest=branch[branch.from])` to see the "matched" numbers and don't see how it relates to your description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## An Rcpp function

I'm not sure if there is any easy way to vectorize the code, so Rcpp may be the best option:

```
library(Rcpp); library(inline)

fun2 <- cppFunction(
    'std::vector<int> branchFrom(NumericVector branch)
{
    std::vector<int> branch_from;
    for(int j = branch.size() - 1; j > 0; j--) {
        int val = -1;
        for(int k = j - 1; k > -1; k--){
            if(branch[j] >= branch[k]){
                val = k;
                break;
            }
        }
        branch_from.push_back(val + 1);
    }
    branch_from.push_back(1);
    std::reverse(branch_from.begin(), branch_from.end());
    return branch_from;
}')
```

Note the the second for-loop won't necessarily iterate through all of `k`, since it stops once a single value `x[k] <= x[j]` is found.

## Analysis

Using `microbenchmark()` from the microbenchmark package where the original implementation is encapsulated in `base`, I get the following:

```
Unit: microseconds
 expr     min       lq     mean  median      uq      max neval
 base 124.232 130.3555 152.7990 133.941 141.176 1048.724   100
 fun2   5.105   5.8145   8.0211   7.137   7.766   79.508   100
```

This indicates a significant speed-up from the original implementation.

Comment: Thank you. I really need to learn how to code. The first 2 million elements took a day using my code; the whole 8 million took seconds with yours.